# df and stat -f difference in blocks count for ext4 filesystem on LVM

Tags: fedora, disk-usage, stat

```
[yotsu@fedora ttyid:2 czw maj 10 19:25:32 ~]$ df -B4K /dev/mapper/fedora-home
System plików            4K-bl użyte dostępne %uż. zamont. na
/dev/mapper/fedora-home 625612 27690   561212   5% /home
[yotsu@fedora ttyid:2 czw maj 10 19:25:41 ~]$ stat -f /home -c "%a %b %f"
561212 625612 597922
[yotsu@fedora ttyid:2 czw maj 10 19:26:07 ~]$ stat -f /dev/mapper/fedora-home -c "%a %b %f"
251736 251736 251736
```

Why does using `stat -f` on `/dev/mapper/fedora-home` give me different values than using it on the directory where its mounted? Which one should I trust?

Comment: What is the output of `stat -f /dev -c "%a %b %f"` ?

Comment: ```[yotsu@fedora ttyid:0 czw maj 10 19:48:42 ~]$ stat -f /dev -c "%a %b %f"

251736 251736 251736```

So its exactly the same, but why does it work like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stat -f /dev/mapper/fedora-home` is giving you the stats for the `/dev` filesystem. This is the expected behaviour. It sounds like you don't want that command.

```
$ stat -f /dev/mapper/alan_dell_2016-home 
  File: "/dev/mapper/alan_dell_2016-home"
    ID: 0        Namelen: 255     Type: tmpfs
Block size: 4096       Fundamental block size: 4096
Blocks: Total: 1002045    Free: 1002045    Available: 1002045
Inodes: Total: 1002045    Free: 1001462
$ df /dev
Filesystem     1K-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs         4008180     0   4008180   0% /dev
```

Comment: Seems to be the case, `df -B4K /dev` reports identical stats. Thanks for help!